# Shared author footnotes in REVTeX

Tags: footnotes, titles, revtex

REVTeX automatically combines `\email` and `\thanks` macros into a single footnote, and uses the same footnote if multiple authors share the exact same set of macros.

Is there any way to force the `\email` and `\thanks` macros to have their own footnotes so that two authors can share the `\thanks` note?

e.g. I would like the author list to look like:

> A. Author,<sup>a),b)</sup> B. Author,<sup>b)</sup> C. Author
>   a) Electronic address: a@example.com
>  b) These two authors
>   contributed equally

The Review of Scientific Instruments [sample manuscript](http://rsi.aip.org/polopoly_fs/1.2322944!/menu/standard/file/RSI_Sample_MS.pdf) does this, however I cannot work out how to get this result in REVTeX.

Comment: Please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) of the "Review of Scientific Instruments" sample manuscript using `revtex4-1`, so the community has something to work with.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you just use `\thanks{These two authors contributed equally}` under both authors, ReVTeX should map them both to the same footnote. Make sure the text is identical. The code below worked for me, had to remove the email though.

```
\documentclass[aip,rsi,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Whatever}

\author{Roger Rabbit}
\thanks{These two authors contributed equally}
\author{Bugs Bunny}
\thanks{These two authors contributed equally}
%\email[E-mail me at:]{bugs@looney.com}
\affiliation{Looney Tune Studios}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

String theory\cite{GSW} attempts to provide a theory of everything.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{GSW} M.~Greene, J.~Schwarz, and
E.~Witten, \textit{Superstring Theory:
Introduction}, (Cambridge University
Press, London, 1985).

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide code showing that this actually works?

Comment: @AndrewSwann yeah, the above worked for me

Comment: Yes, it seems to work, but it is very sensitive to the presence of other fields, so will only work in limited cases.

Comment: Can you also incorporate the email address?

Answer (score 1):

*Not a real answer, but to long for a comment.*

I don't think that your desired layout is a standard option in `REVTeX`. Note that the [sample manuscript](http://rsi.aip.org/polopoly_fs/1.2322944!/menu/standard/file/RSI_Sample_MS.pdf) (which you refer to) are created using MS Word `:-(`.

You can naturally circumvent such limitations, but I fear that this might give you problems when you submit your manuscript. I've been told (I don't know if it's correct), that the APS & AIP journals convert the submitted manuscripts to some non-TeX format.

An example, which partly answer your question (sadly with very little flexibility) is given below.

```
\documentclass[aip,rsi,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Whatever}

\author{Roger Rabbit}
\thanks{These two authors contributed equally}
\author{Bugs Bunny\normalfont\textsuperscript{a,}}
\email[E-mail me at:]{bugs@looney.com}
\affiliation{Looney Tune Studios}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

String theory\cite{GSW} attempts to provide a theory of everything.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{GSW} M.~Greene, J.~Schwarz, and
E.~Witten, \textit{Superstring Theory:
Introduction}, (Cambridge University
Press, London, 1985).

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

**Remark:** Bugs Bunny's email address is taken directly from the `REVTeX`-manual and I don't know if it's an actual email `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with a few asterisks an extra `\affil` tag.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{authblk}

\begin{document}

\title{My title}
\author[1]{Bugs Bunny*} % asterisk
\author[1]{Donald Duck*} % asterisk
\affil[1]{Loony Tunes}
\affil[*]{Authors contributed equally} % extra affiliation

\maketitle

\end{document}
```