# Separate and shared author footnotes in REVTeX

Tags: footnotes, revtex, affiliation

I would like to have the following scenario in the author section of my paper. Two footnotes for the first author: one for the email address and a second one,  shared with author two, stating their equal contribution to the paper. REVTeX seems to combine \email and \thanks automatically

This is what I would like to have:

```
A. Author$^{1,2}$, B. Author$^{2}$

1 A.Author@example.com
2 These two authors contributed equally
```

The same question was asked here as well, but no answer was provided [Shared author footnotes in REVTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98299/shared-author-footnotes-in-revtex)

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[reprint,superscriptaddress,amsmath,amssymb,aps,pra]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
\preprint{APS/123-QED}
\title{How to have two separate footnotes for the first author}

\author{A. Author}
\email{A.Author@example.com}
\thanks{These two authors contributed equally }
\affiliation{Department of Physics}
\affiliation{Department of Chemistry}
\author{B. Author}
\thanks{These two authors contributed equally }
\affiliation{Department of Electrical Engineering}
\affiliation{Department of Physics}
\author{C. Author}
\affiliation{Department of Electrical Engineering}

\date{\today}
\begin{abstract}
Hello!
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this problem? I'm also interesting in the very same thing.