# Problem with shared author footnotes in REVTeX4-2

Tags: footnotes, revtex, email

When two authors share the same `\thanks` footnote and both `\email` are provided, for example,

```
\author{Author A}
\email{authorA@mail}
\thanks{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
\author{Author B}
\email{authorB@mail}
\thanks{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
\author{Author C}
\email{authorC@mail}
```

REVTeX cannot correctly display them as

> Author A,<sup>*,†</sup> Author B,<sup>‡,†</sup> and Author C<sup>¶</sup>
> * authorA@mail
>  ‡ authorB@mail
>  ¶ authorC@mail
> † These authors contributed equally to this work.

Instead, REVTeX automatically combines `\email` and `\thanks` macros to one footnote for every author, and the authors are displayed as

[image]

The footnote becomes

[image]

The document class and the loaded packages are

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,bbm,xcolor}
```

I noticed two historical posts on this issue ([post 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344400/separate-and-shared-author-footnotes-in-revtex) and [post 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98299/shared-author-footnotes-in-revtex)), but all the solutions are not perfect.
For example, in [the second post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98299/shared-author-footnotes-in-revtex), the first answer cannot incorporate the email address; the second answer looks OK. But the superscript added in that way directly follows the author name and goes before the comma. The position is slightly different compared to other superscripts.
Moreover, if both equal-contribution authors have their emails present, the second answer cannot work either.

Since the two previous questions were posted several years ago, I wonder if any solution to this issue was posted somewhere that I didn't find.

Comment: I'm also having the same problem...

Comment: Did you every have any luck with this problem? I'm trying to solve the same thing now.