# Merged author affiliation footnotes in REVTeX

Tags: footnotes, revtex, affiliation

(My previous question was closed as a duplicate despite me explaining how the suggested answers do not answer it at all. Please read until the end before voting to close.)

The REVTeX package automatically merges some footnotes in the author list. For instance, consider the following.

```
\documentclass[superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\author{Author A}
\thanks{Footnote.}
\affiliation{University A}
\affiliation{University B}

\author{Author B}
\thanks{Footnote.}
\affiliation{University B}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Here, the repeated footnotes (affiliation B and the `\thanks` footnote) are merged:

[image]

However, adding email addresses messes things up.

```
\documentclass[superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

\author{Author A}
\thanks{Footnote.}
\email{a@a.edu}
\affiliation{University A}
\affiliation{University B}

\author{Author B}
\thanks{Footnote.}
\email{b@b.edu}
\affiliation{University B}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to merge the common `\thanks` footnote, but keep the email footnotes separate. Altogether, this would give 3 footnotes, with each author having two (in addition to affiliation). Is this possible with REVTeX? If not, is there an easy way to patch it to allow for this behavior?

---

This issue was previously raised [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98299/shared-author-footnotes-in-revtex). The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362301/223505) does not provide a solution to the problem, as it uses only *one* affiliation footnote (e.g. `\thanks` but no `\email`), in which case REVTeX handles everything well. The solution in that answer does not work when two different footnotes are used, as I have explicitly demonstrated above, and as has been pointed out in the comments to that answer.

A workaround is to put the `\email` after `\affiliation`, but this places the footnote mark in the affiliation instead of next to the author's name, and it only works when there is no ambiguity (no affiliation shared between different authors).